# Vector iterator > vector.end() even though the vector should not have been reallocated

Tags: c++

First: I am happy to update the question in the title if someone can think of a more concise way to put it.

Here's the situation:

I have a vector as class member. After extracting an element from the vector with the following:

```
inline int currentToken()
{
    /* __it is of type std::vector <int>::iterator */

    return (__it < __tokens.begin()) ? Syntax::OUT_OF_RANGE_BEGIN :
           (__it > __tokens.end())   ? Syntax::OUT_OF_RANGE_END :
           *__it;
}
```

The returned integer is exactly as expected (in this case, a 65, which is what it should have been).

Now is where things get tricky, however. When this particular token is encountered, it sparks a new chain of events and the previous tokens in the vector need to be discarded.

First, I call the class' 'saveLocation' member function, which is an inline quickie:

```
__saved_it = __it;
```

Then, I call the 'truncateHead' member function, which is where the error occurs. Before the code, I would like to point out that none of the above has in any way *changed* the vector, so there is absolutely no reason for the vector's memory to have been reallocated.

```
__it = __tokens.erase(__tokens.begin(), __saved_it+1); //segfault
```

Some debugging has revealed that somehow `__it` is greater than `__tokens.end()`, even though it is still both larger than `__begin` *and* dereferenced to the number '65' as expected.

How is it not in the range between `__tokens.begin()` and `__tokens.end()`?

In fact, this situation is already present in the `saveLocation` method above.

Remembering that `currentToken()` is immediately followed by `saveLocation()`, and `currentToken` would have returned the integral representation of `OUT_OF_RANGE_END` if the iterator were already out of range, I am flummoxed.

Completely and utterly.

Comment: Please don't put tag information in your title (especially not by using `[]`, which is used for marking duplicate/on hold questions here). The tagging system here is very good at classifying things, and doesn't need help. :-) Please see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661). Thanks.

Comment: I hope `Syntax::OUT_OF_RANGE_END` isn't 65?! Well from what you present here, nobody can tell what might cause __it to be in range first and out of range immediately after. You might need to add additional code. ;)

Comment: No, OUT_OF_RANGE_END is close to climit INT_MAX (it's all generated via an automated script).

Comment: One thing to note is that after erase the memory is reallocated and any saved __it is no longer valid.

Comment: Yes. I have things in place for that, and of course __it itself is set with that statement.

Comment: `tokens.end()` returns a past the end iterator. That is, it is already outside of the range. When you check if `__it` is past the last element then you should evaluate if the iterator is bigger or equal to `tokens.end()`.

Comment: @TomThorogood when you say __it is past end that is after the call to erase right?

Comment: @snipes83 -- Very good point. Making that change and will report back.

Comment: @snipes83 That was the problem. Wow. i feel so moronic now. Please put that as an answer so you can get the credit you deserve!

Comment: @TomThorogood Glad to be of help :)

Comment: Don't start your variable names with underscores.

Comment: More specifically, names starting with underscores are reserved for the compiler and system libraries. If you need to differentiate members use a trailing underscore.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names containing two underscores (`__it`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: @PeteBecker (et alia): Just wanted to let you know that after having some really, really weird compiler errors (files were inconsistently not compiling, and the problem was always listed in native code I didn't write), I gave all this advice some thought and removed the double underscores. The issues disappeared. So, thanks! And know that your advice didn't go unheard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tokens.end()` returns a past the end iterator. That is, it is already outside of the range.

It's not meaningful to compare if an iterator is bigger than (`>`) a past the end iterator, as iterators only range from `begin()` to `end()`. Because of the same reason, it is also not meaningful to check if an iterator is less than the iterator returned by `begin()`.

This means that there's no way of checking if an iterator is `OUT_OF_RANGE_BEGIN` or `OUT_OF_RANGE_END`. You can only check if it's inside the valid range or not.

It's ok to check if an iterator is bigger than or equal to (`>=`) the iterator returned by `begin()`.

When you check if `__it` is past the last element then you should evaluate if the iterator is not equal to `tokens.end()`

E.g. you should check for something like

```
return (__it >= __tokens.begin()
     && __it != __tokens.end()) ? *__it : Syntax::OUT_OF_RANGE;
```

This also requires that you do not increment the iterator past the containers past-the-end-iterator. Accessing memory pointed to by an iterator that has been incremented past the `end()`-iterator will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Iterator comparisons are only meaningful for iterators that point into the same range (the definition is that the lesser iterator can be incremented to reach the greater one). Testing whether an iterator is `>` the end iterator for a container doesn't do anything meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

Iterator comparisons are only valid for iterators that point into the same range. Testing whether an iterator is `<` the `begin` iterator of a container or `>` the end iterator of a container does not do anything meaningful.